# How to get public pics from instagram with their username using APIs

Tags: instagram-api

How to get public pics of other user with their username in instagram APIs??

I am trying to get the public pictures of given user with their username from instagram

Answer (score 0):

The current instagram api requires you to get an access token for a user in order to get a users public media.
At the time you get the access token you will have the instagram userId.  You will be able to store token along with the id and then request it using the ID instead of the username.

However, in this scenario you will not need the username in the request since you will be getting the media for the tokens "self".  You will probably just end up linking the access token to their username in your data store.

Comment: Thanks Mike! But how do we get access_tokens for other userids. It is something confidential.. right?

Comment: You are required to have the user go through the Auth flow using Oauth2.  In that flow, the user will be prompted to log in and a token associated with your app will be issued with the permissions they consented to.  The Basic instagram permission will give you access to their public info.  You can then grab the token in the response (in the url ) and store that for the user.  Then you include that token for any requests on behalf of the user.